# What's happening underneath a Fetch Request Template that improves performance?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I was curious if there was a performance gain from creating a Fetch Request Template versus programmatically creating NSFetchRequest so I wrote some tests to measure this. [Here's the source on github](https://github.com/jinyk/CoreDataFetchTests).

Same order of difference in Simulator and on iPhone (measuring time interval to do a bunch of fetches):

```
just creating an NSFetchRequest:          4.399674
creating a Fetch Request Template:        0.501369
NSFetchRequest with field indexed:        0.407068
Fetch Request Template and field indexed: 0.281876
```

It turns out there's about 7~9 times performance gain in creating a Fetch Request Template. I thought maybe it's creating the proper index underneath but when I created an Fetch Request Template that matches on an indexed field, there's even a further performance benefit.

Ok, nice to know that this is the case, but I would very much like to know what the heck is happening underneath the Fetch Request Template that accounts for performance gains?

Comment: How complex is the predicate in use? Normally there's the overhead of compiling the predicate, whic can be avoided by using a template or caching a previously used predicate

Comment: Very simple. The data I used was SAT scores from PA high schools (opendataphilly.org) and I tried matching a specific score and a randomized score. I think I have a bit more info on this question, I'm verify before I post an update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update

After some profiling with Instruments, it turns out `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` is not the culprit here!

The actual cause of the performance difference is **sort descriptors**.

The non-template tests are using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, which requires a sort descriptor, whereas the template-based ones do not specify a sort descriptor.

If you add a sort descriptor to all the tests, the performance evens out (with the exception of the indexed case.)

---

### Original (wrong) answer

The performance penalty is because your 'just creating a NSFetchRequest' test calls `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` for each iteration of the loop - this is *very slow*!

Think about it - `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` has to parse the string and basically compile it into the internal representation used by Core Data.

The usual solution is to only call `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` once, and then use `[NSPredicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:]` to specify the values that will be compared by the predicate - this is covered in the [Core Data Documentation - Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW3)

> To create a predicate from a formatted string, the framework must
>   parse the string and create instances of predicate and expression
>   objects. If you are using the same form of a predicate many times over
>   but changing the value of one of the constant value expressions on
>   each use, it is more efficient to create a predicate once and then use
>   variable substitution (see “Creating Predicates”).

Comment: You're spot on. Although Michael rightfully pointed out that the performance difference between fetch request template and fetch request built in code with indexed field was minimal and in fact could well have been caused by the overhead of parsing and creating extra objects, I'll grant you the bounty for your effort and precise explanation.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is largely the right answer! As I mentioned in a comment to Mike Abdullah, I did realize this difference in sort descriptors and once I put an index on the column I was sorting on the results more or less evened out. I was trying to find the time to rewrite the test code on github and update with real numbers but you beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html):

> Stored fetch requests can include placeholders for variable
>   substitution, and so serve as templates for later completion. Fetch
>   request templates therefore allow you to pre-define queries with
>   variables that are substituted at runtime.

Also, see the Stored Fetch Requests section of the [NSManagedObjectModel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

It seems like the biggest advantage might come from the fact that the query does not have to be built at runtime -- it is pre-built and then variables are substituted into the query when appropriate.

Comment: While all you say is true, I find it hard to believe that building the query is taking so much time (a little below 4 seconds for a simple query).

Comment: Well, the difference is much smaller when the fields are indexed, and I think that the .12 second difference could certainly be due to the time it takes to parse a predicate and build an NSFetchRequest. I do agree that 4 seconds is a huge difference, though. Can you show the fetch request you are building?